# How to change the html background using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background to the whole html of my website I set this using CSS :

```
html { 
        background: url('../include-uploads/backgrounds/ironman1.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: cover;
        -moz-background-size: cover;
        -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
}
```

I want to change this background automatically each few seconds. I tried to use this jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
              $('html').css({"background":"url(include-uploads/backgrounds/ironman2.jpg) no-repeat});
            }, 5000);

    });
```

But it showed the background image as small image in the top left of the website and not covering all the page. so I tried to add some background attributes as following :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
              $('html').css({"background":"url(include-uploads/backgrounds/ironman2.jpg) no-repeat,background-size: cover"});
            }, 5000);

    });
```

But there is no response and the image does not show anymore . Is there a way to do this in jquery should I add something to that code or edit something ??

Comment: `-webkit-background-size` and other are separate rules, you should define them as `"-webkit-background-size" : "cover"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the closing quotes (after no-repeat `"` is missing) in below script, add it and try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setTimeout(function(){
      $('html').css({"background":"url(include-uploads/backgrounds/ironman2.jpg) no-repeat"});
     }, 5000);

 });
```

and in second try, you have given all attribute values for `background` attribute only. every css attribute should be assigned separately.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   setTimeout(function(){
       $('html').css({"background":"url(include-uploads/backgrounds/ironman2.jpg) no-repeat"});
       $('html').css({"-webkit-background-size":"cover"});
       $('html').css({"-moz-background-size":"cover"});
       $('html').css({"-o-background-size":"cover"});
       $('html').css({"background-size":"cover"});
     }, 5000);

});
```